# Test driven development for signal processing libraries

Tags: unit-testing, audio, language-agnostic, tdd, signal-processing

I work with audio manipulation, generally using Matlab for prototyping, and C++ for implementation. Recently, I have been reading up on TDD. I have looked over a few basic examples and am quite enthusiastic about the paradigm.

At the moment, I use what I would consider a global 'test-assisted' approach. For this, I write signal processing blocks in C++, and then I make a simple Matlab mex file that can interface with my classes. I subsequently add functionality, checking that the results match up with an equivalent Matlab script as I go. This works ok, but the tests become obsolete quickly as the system evolves. Furtermore, I am testing the whole system, not just units.

It would be nice to use an established TDD framework where I can have a test suite, but I don't see how I can validate the functionality of the processing blocks without tests that are equally as complex as the code under test. How would I generate the reference signals in a C++ test to validate a processing block without the test being a form of self-fulfilling prophecy?

If anyone has experience in this area, or can suggest some methodologies that I could read into, then that would be great.

Comment: +1 testing signal processing is not easy; one note though: testing that c++ results are the same as matlab results only proves that point, but doesn't prove that the results are correct: both matlab and c++ might give the same, incorrect, result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's great to apply the TDD approach to signal processing (it would have saved me months of time if I knew about it years ago when I was doing signal processing myself).  I think the key is to break down your system into the lowest level components that can be independently tested, eg:

- FFTs: test signals at known frequencies: DC, Fs/Nfft, Fs/2 and different phases etc. Check the peaks and phase are as you expect, check the normalisation constant is as you expect
- peak picking: test that you correctly find maxima/minima
- Filters: generate input at known frequencies and check the output amplitude and phase is as expected.

You are unlikely to get *exactly* the same results out between C++ and Matlab, so you'll have to supply error bounds on some of the tests.  TDD is a great way of not only verifying the correctness of the code you have but is really useful when trying out different implementations. For example if you want to replace one FFT implementation with another, there are often slight differences with the way the data is packed, or the normalisation constant that is used.  TDD will give you a high degree of confidence the new library is correctly integrated.

Answer (score 2):

I do something similar for heuristics detection, and we have loads and loads of capture files and a framework to be able to load and inject them for testing. Do you have the possibility to capture the reference signals in a file and do the same?

As for my 2 cents regarding TDD, its a great way to develop, but as with most paradigms, you dont always have to follow it to the letter, there are times when you should know how to bend the rules a bit, so as not to write too much throw-away code/tests. I read about one approach that said absolutely no code should be written until a test is developed, which at times can be way too strict.

On the other hand, I always like to say: "If its not tested, its broken" :)

Answer (score 1):

It's OK for the test to be as complex or more complex than the code under development.  If you change (update, refactor, bug fix) the code and not the test, the unit test will warn you that something changed and needs to be reviewed (was a bug fix for mode A supposed to change mode B?, etc.)

Furthermore, you can maintain the APIs for the individual compute components, and not just for the entire end-to-end system.

Answer (score 0):

I've only just starting thinking about TDD in the context of signal processing, so I can only add a bit to the previous answers. What I've done is exploit a bit of superposition to test primitives. For example, testing an IIR filter, I independently verified b0, b1, and b2 elements with unit and scaled gains, and then verified a1 and a2 elements that followed easily modeled decays. My test signal was a combination of ramp functions for the numerator and impulse functions for the denominator. I know it's a trivial example, but the process should work for plenty of linear operations. Tests should also exercise unstable regions and show that outputs explode appropriately.

In general, I expect that impulse responses are going to do a lot of the work for me, since many situations will see them reduce to trigonometric functions, which can be independently calculated. Similarly, if your operation has a series expansion, your test function could perform the expansion to a relevant order and compare against against your processing block. It'll be slow, but it should work.